# Request Body got removed after converting .har file to .jmx JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

If you already have a Fiddler recording you can export the captured requests in HAR format like File -> Export Sessions -> HTTP Archive 1.1 and once done you can convert them into JMeter .jmx script using online HAR to JMX conversion tool

As suggested I have done below steps:
1) Fiddler session exported to .har file
2) .har files converted to .jmx file using https://converter.blazemeter.com/
3) uploaded .jmx to Jmeter

in this process request body got removed. Please suggest on this.
[Jmeter Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL6DH.png)

[Fiddler Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B9C3.png)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that anyone here will be able to help as it's a proprietary tool by [BlazeMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/), you can try [opening a support ticket](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-open-a-support-ticket-) and describe your problem there.

---

In the meantime you can convert your Fiddler recordings into a JMeter test by replaying the requests via JMeter

1. Start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)
2. Configure [Firefox to use JMeter as the proxy](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/connection-settings-firefox)
3. Open [Firefox Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor)
4. Drag and drop your .har file there
5. Click "Resend" on each request
6. JMeter should capture the requests under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)